# Xcode 9.X Always opens Xcode 8.x Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9, simulator

I have facing issue since I upgraded the xcode from 8.x to 9.x. Once I downloaded the latest xcode 9.1 and run the project on it, it always open xcode 8.x's simulator not xcode 9's Simulator.I am very much confuse why this happening.
After that I have downloaded latest XCODE 9.4.1 and run the project .
Same issue  i am facing open xcode 8.x's Simulator on Xcode 9.4.1

Please help me guys if any one idea why this is happening.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why don't you just delete Xcode 8? :)

Comment: I have already delete it :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your Simulator is Working Fine.You should check your simulator bezels.
Got to the Simulator and Make sure to check "**show device bezels**" Option.

Comment: Yes ,Exactly I got the issues.By default my simulator bezels deselect.
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Earlier i got the same issue :)

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Xcode **Preferences** Delete all the Derived Data and Archives from **Locations** and Make sure select Xcode 9.4.1 in Command Line Tools then **Force Quite** Xcode 8 and Launch Xcode 9.

[image]

Comment: @hd1344 How many Xcode Display in **Command Line Tools** Option in Your System?

Comment: @hd1344 Try this one "Simulator -> Hardware -> Erase All Content and Settings" and let me know that which iOS Version Display below the launched Simulator?